# Scroll Indicator and uiScrollView methods

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, indicator

When you drag or flick scroll the Scroll Indicators appear then when everything stops moving they disappear.

I would like to do some stuff during this time (or while they are showing)

I know I could use (void) scrollViewDidScroll to start my things, but, and here is the question, is there a single method for the end?

I know there are individual methods for drag or deceleration (after a flick) but there must be a single one because I bet that Scroll Indicator is using it???

many thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm using:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *) _theScroller{

    [self startJob];//start doing stuff!
}
```

and:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating: (UIScrollView *) _theScroller{

    [self stopJob];//stop doing stuff!
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *) _theScroller willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {

    [self stopJob];//stop doing stuff!
}
```

I seems I have to use the two methods to stop, one if you just 'flick' the scroll and let it stop, and the other if you drag about without 'flicking'.